# Change table height (resize) by dragging the bottom border

Tags: tabulator

What needs to be done to setup a `tabulator.js` table such that the table is resizable by dragging the bottom border? Result should be similar to what is shown in the video linked bellow.

https://i.imgur.com/0G2RNTJ.mp4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bellow is a working example code based on [the answer from Oli](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64975603/14512005) and the idea of using a `table.setHeight()` call.

```
<div class="container page-section">

<div class="resizable">
  <div class="resizers">
    <div id="example-table"></div>
      <div class="resizer-line bottom-line"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
        
  <h3>Text below</h3>
        
</div>
```

```
body {
    font-family: "Segoe UI","Helvetica Neue",Arial,"Noto Sans",sans-serif;
    font-size: 1rem;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.5;
    color: #212529;
    text-align: left;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 740px;
}

.page-section {
    padding-top: 3.5rem;
    padding-bottom: 3.5rem;
}

.resizable {
  position: relative;
  background: white;
}

.resizable .resizers {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer-line {
  position: relative;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer-line.bottom-line {
  height: 3px;
  border-top: 1px solid #51899C;
  cursor: ns-resize;
}

.resizable .resizers .resizer-line.bottom-line:hover {
  border-top: 1px solid #83bbce;
}
```

```
var tableData = [
    {id:1, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", gender:"male", height:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", gender:"female", height:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:6, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    {id:7, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
    {id:8, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
    {id:9, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", gender:"male", height:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:10, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", gender:"female", height:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
    {id:11, name:"Billy Bob", age:"12", gender:"male", height:1, col:"red", dob:"", cheese:1},
    {id:12, name:"Mary May", age:"1", gender:"female", height:2, col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982", cheese:true},
    {id:13, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", height:0, col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982", cheese:"true"},
    {id:14, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", gender:"male", height:1, col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:15, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", gender:"female", height:5, col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
]
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
    data:tableData,           //set initial table data
    height:300,
    layout:"fitColumns",      //fit columns to width of table
    responsiveLayout:"hide",  //hide columns that dont fit on the table
    tooltips:true,            //show tool tips on cells
    addRowPos:"top",          //when adding a new row, add it to the top of the table
    history:true,             //allow undo and redo actions on the table
    movableColumns:true,      //allow column order to be changed
    initialSort:[             //set the initial sort order of the data
        {column:"name", dir:"asc"},
    ],
    columns:[
        {title:"Name", field:"name"},
        {title:"Age", field:"age"},
        {title:"Gender", field:"gender"},
        {title:"Height", field:"height"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", field:"dob"},
        {title:"Cheese Preference", field:"cheese"},
    ],
});

function makeResizableDiv(div) {
  const element = document.querySelector(div);
  const resizers = element.querySelectorAll('.resizer-line')
  const minimum_size = 90;
  let original_width = 0;
  let original_height = 0;
  let original_x = 0;
  let original_y = 0;
  let original_mouse_x = 0;
  let original_mouse_y = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < resizers.length; i++) {
    const currentResizer = resizers[i];
    currentResizer.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault()
      original_width = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('width').replace('px', ''));
      original_height = parseFloat(getComputedStyle(element, null).getPropertyValue('height').replace('px', ''));
      original_x = element.getBoundingClientRect().left;
      original_y = element.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      original_mouse_x = e.pageX;
      original_mouse_y = e.pageY;
      window.addEventListener('mousemove', resize)
      window.addEventListener('mouseup', stopResize)
    })
    
    function resize(e) {
      if (currentResizer.classList.contains('bottom-line')) {
        const height = original_height + (e.pageY - original_mouse_y);
        if (height > minimum_size) {
          table.setHeight(height - 23);
          element.style.height = height + 'px';
        }
      }
    }
    
    function stopResize() {
      window.removeEventListener('mousemove', resize)
    }
  }
}

makeResizableDiv('.resizable');
```

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator will respond to a resize of the element containing it, so if you make the containing element resizable, your table will automatically redraw itself when it is resized.

This article takes you through how to build up a resizable div yourself:
https://medium.com/the-z/making-a-resizable-div-in-js-is-not-easy-as-you-think-bda19a1bc53d

Or if you are looking for a quick solution i would recommend using one of the many resizable JavaScript libraries that are out there that will make the process much easier.

Comment: Oli, I've followed the tutorial you linked and got this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/n045u18o/), afterwards I've tried to make a tabulator table resizable with a bottom border dragger and I'm not having any luck [link](https://jsfiddle.net/nzak9sm7/), the table isn't resizing

Comment: Without a link to a JS Fiddle that demonstrates your attempt it is hard to offer you advice on where the issue may lie

Comment: Oh, you mean those two links in the above comment don't work? https://jsfiddle.net/n045u18o/ https://jsfiddle.net/nzak9sm7/ Odd.

Comment: I did it. Thank you, Oli. `table.setHeight()` was the last missing piece of the puzzle.